# Implementing an enum ForwardIndexType

Tags: swift, enums

I have been struggling to properly implement the `ForwardIndexType` protocol for an enum, in particular the handling of the end case (i.e for the last item without a successor). This protocol is not really covered in the Swift Language book.

Here is a simple example

```
enum ThreeWords : Int, ForwardIndexType {
    case one=1, two, three

    func successor() ->ThreeWords {
            return ThreeWords(rawValue:self.rawValue + 1)!
    }
}
```

The `successor()` function will return the next enumerator value, except for the last element, where it will fail with an exception, because there is no value after `.three`

The `ForwardTypeProtocol` does not allow `successor()` to return a conditional value, so there seems to be no way of signalling that there is no successor.

Now using this in a for loop to iterate over the closed range of all the possible values of an enum, one runs into a problem for the end case:

```
for word in ThreeWords.one...ThreeWords.three {
    print("   \(word.rawValue)")
}
println()

//Crashes with the error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Swift inexplicably calls the `successor()` function of the end value of the range, before executing the statements in the for loop. If the range is left half open `ThreeWords.one..<ThreeWords.three` then the code executes correctly, printing `1  2`

If I modify the successor function so that it does not try to create a value larger than `.three` like this

```
   func successor() ->ThreeWords {
        if self == .three {
            return .three
        } else {
            return ThreeWords(rawValue:self.rawValue + 1)!
        }
    }
```

Then the for loop does not crash, but it also misses the last iteration, printing the same as if the range was half open `1  2`

My conclusion is that there is a bug in swift's for loop iteration; it should not call `successor()` on the end value of a closed range. Secondly, the `ForwardIndexType` ought to be able to return an optional, to be able to signal that there is no successor for a certain value.

Has anyone had more success with this protocol ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it seems that `successor` will be called on the last value.

[image]

You may wish to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/), but to work around this you could simply add a sentinel value to act as a successor.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, `...` operator

```
func ...<Pos : ForwardIndexType>(minimum: Pos, maximum: Pos) -> Range<Pos>
```

calls `maximum.successor()`. It constructs `Range<T>` like

```
Range(start: minimum, end: maximum.successor())
```

So, If you want to use `enum` as `Range.Index`, you have to define the **next** of the last value.

```
enum ThreeWords : Int, ForwardIndexType {
    case one=1, two, three
    case EXHAUST

    func successor() ->ThreeWords {
        return ThreeWords(rawValue:self.rawValue + 1) ?? ThreeWords.EXHAUST
    }
}
```

Comment: That sucks because now all my enum switch statements are infected with a required default case

Answer (score 2):

This is an old Question but I would like to sum up some things and post another possible solution.

As @jtbandes and @rintaro already stated a closed range created with the `start...end` operator is internally created with `start..<end.successor()`
Afaik this is an intentional behavior in Swift.

In many cases you can also use an `Interval` where you thought about using a `Range` or where Swift declared a *Range* by default. The point here is that *intervals* aren't collections.

So this is **not** possible with *Intervals*

```
for word in ThreeWords.one...ThreeWords.three {...}
```

================

For the following I assume the snippet above was just a debug case to cross-check the values.

To declare an Interval you need to explicitly specify the type. Either a `HalfOpenInterval (..<)` or a `ClosedInterval (...)`

```
var interval:ClosedInterval = ThreeWords.one...ThreeWords.four
```

This requires you to make your enumeration `Comparable`. Although `Int` is `Comparable` already, you still need to add it to the inheritance list

```
enum ThreeWords : Int, ForwardIndexType, Comparable {
    case one=1, two, three, four

    func successor() ->ThreeWords {
        return ThreeWords(rawValue:self.rawValue + 1)!
    }
}
```

And finally the enumeration need to conform to `Comparable`. This is a generic approach since your enumeration also conforms to the protocol `RawRepresentable`

```
func <<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue: Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
}
```

Like I wrote you can't iterate over it in a loop anymore, but you can have a quick cross-check using a switch:

```
var interval:ClosedInterval = ThreeWords.one...ThreeWords.four
switch(ThreeWords.four) {
    case ThreeWords.one...ThreeWords.two:
        print("contains one or two")
    case let word where interval ~= word:
        print("contains: \(word) with raw value: \(word.rawValue)")
    default:
        print("no case")
}
```

prints "*contains: four with raw value: 4*"